# Pandas stack chart with multiple dataframes

Tags: plot, pandas, stack

I have a multiple dataframes (each dataframe is a picked file) which look like this:

```
   DB Size                 Time
0    blue   19  2000-01-01 00:00:00
1   green   17  2000-01-01 01:00:00
2     red   20  2000-01-01 02:00:00
3  yellow   18  2000-01-01 03:00:00
4     red   17  2000-01-01 04:00:00
5  yellow   12  2000-01-01 05:00:00
6   green   14  2000-01-01 06:00:00
7  yellow    7  2000-01-01 07:00:00
8    blue   13  2000-01-01 08:00:00
9     red   12  2000-01-01 09:00:00
```

I would like to build a stack graph for Size with these intervals (0-5,6-10,11-15,16-25). The x-axis would be Time (1 day).

So, I have another DataFrame which is for another day

Which looks similar.

```
       DB Size                 Time
0  yellow   18  2000-01-02 00:00:00
1    blue   15  2000-01-02 01:00:00
2   green    3  2000-01-02 02:00:00
3     red    6  2000-01-02 03:00:00
4     red   17  2000-01-02 04:00:00
5   green   18  2000-01-02 05:00:00
6   green   16  2000-01-02 06:00:00
7    blue    9  2000-01-02 07:00:00
8  yellow    5  2000-01-02 08:00:00
9     red   16  2000-01-02 09:00:00
```

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Not merged yet, but this PR will be helpful: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/pull/6656. You can take a look at the code and do something similar if you want.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you can do this.

Assuming your data are in df1, df2, or more :

```
df=pd.concat([df1,df2])

df['Date'] = [d.date() for d in df['Time'] ]
df['Size_Interval'] = pd.cut(df['Size'],bins=[0,5,10,15,25])

count_df = df.pivot_table(rows='Date', cols='Size_Interval', values='DB', aggfunc=len)
count_df.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True)
```